# SSL and www to non-www redirection works only on homepage - Wordpress

Tags: redirect, htaccess, ssl

I've enabled SSL on my Wordpress website and set redirection from www to non-WWW via the following code placed in .htaccess:

```
# REDIRECT WWW TO NON-WWW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# REDIRECT HTTP TO HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, it works good only on homepage (example.com). What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't your redirect directives be at the top of the file? Why is the WP section repeated twice?

Comment: @TomJNowell They should - I just changed it - thank you! As for the repeated WP section, I have no idea how that happened. Just fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put the directives in the wrong place, the canoncial redirects need to go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section (the front-controller), otherwise, they are not going to be processed for anything other than physical files and directories. (The "homepage" maps to a physical directory, so *is* redirected).

For some reason you have also repeated the WordPress front-controller section, with a slight difference. You should only have one.

> ```
> # BEGIN block author scans
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (author=\d+) [NC]
> RewriteRule .* - [F]
> # END block author scans
> ```

This section is also in the wrong place and needs to go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section. You should remove the `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` directives from this block.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works great :)

Here's my new updated .htaccess file: https://pastebin.com/gcnfv8gc - does it look good now?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, your new updated `.htaccess` file looks OK. Minor point, but there's no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive. Just have it once inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` section and you don't need it anywhere else. (Only the _last_ instance of the `RewriteEngine` directive actually does anything.)

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind :-)